# What makes a component fail to update its template when a Boolean value changes, in the Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular

In an Angular 11 app, I have a simle service that mekes a `get` request and reads a JSON.

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Promo } from '../models/promo';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PromoService {

 public apiURL: string;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiURL = `https://api.url.com/`;
  }

  public getPromoData(){
    return this.http.get<Promo>(`${this.apiURL}/promo`);
  }
}
```

In the the component, I need to compare the array of *products* with the array of *campaign products* (included in the JSON mantioned above) and *higlight the promoted products*:

```
export class ProductCardComponent extends DestroyableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges
{

     public promoData: any;
     public promoProducts: any;
     public isPromoProduct: boolean = false;
     
     
     public ngOnInit() {
         this.getCampaignData();
     }
     
     public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.getCampaignData();
      }
     
     
     public getPromoData() {
        this.promoService.getPromoData().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(data => {
          this.promoData = data;
          this.promoProducts = this.promoData.products;

          let promoProduct = this.promoProducts.find((product:any) => { 
            return this.product.unique_identifier == product.unique_identifier;
          });

          if (promoProduct) {
              // Update boolean
              this.isPromoProduct = true;
            }
        });
     }
 
 }
```

In the component's html file (template), I have:

```
<span *ngIf="isPromoProduct" class="promo">Promo</span>
```

There are **no compilation errors**.

#### The problem

For a reason I have been unable to understand, the template does not react to the change of the variable `isPromoProduct` and the template is not updated, despite the fact that I call the function inside `ngOnInit` *and* `ngOnChanges`.

###### Questions:

1. Where is my mistake?
2. What is a reliable way to update the template?

Comment: have check the value of promoProduct before if condition by debugging and where you are calling getPromoData method in your ProductCardComponent?

Comment: What change detection strategy are you using exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subscribing` to `Observable` inside `.ts` file it's mostly not a best practice.
try to avoid it by using `async pipe` of `Angular`.

you need to store the observable in the variable and not the data returned from the observable, for example:

```
// this variable holds the `observable` itself.
this.promoData$ = this.promoService.getPromoData()
```

and then in the template you can do it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="promoData$ | async as promoData">
  here you can access the promoData
</div>
```

you can still use `pipe()` to map the data etc but avoid the `subscribe()`

Comment: Watch out how many times you use this technique in your template, as it can lead to multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: of course - when you need to do it multiple times, simply create one `Observable` that contained all `Observables` and wrap the template with it as `async pipe`

Comment: That's not what I meant. It will fire an additional request (the same request) for each occurence of `promoData$ | async` from the template file.

Comment: ha Ok, I got you now  - so the answer is to wrap all implementation of it in one `async pipe` - this will make only one request

Comment: I think your answer covers it already. If you use the property `this.promoData$` to store the observable returned by `this.promoService.getPromoData()` then it won't make additional requests. Only if you use `this.promoService.getPromoData() | async` directly in the template multiple times, as it will return a new observable for every function call.

Comment: there's a comment on your question that you didn't answer yet - check this out  - it is necessary for trying to understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

The `isPromoProduct` boolean is not an input. The `ngOnChanges` gets triggered for changes on your properties that are decorated with the `@Input` decorator. For your particular case, you can inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` and trigger change detection manually:

```js
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  // ...
public getPromoData() {
  this.promoService.getPromoData().subscribe(data => {
          // ...

          if (promoProduct) {
              // Update boolean
              this.isPromoProduct = true;
              this.cdr.detectChanges();
            }
        });
}
```

You also don't need to manage `httpClient` subscriptions. The observables generated by a simple `get` or `post` request will complete after they emit the response of the request. You only need to explicitly manage the unsubscribe for hot observables (that you create from subjects that you instantiate yourself).